# How to find the longest substring with equal amount of characters efficiently

Tags: java, algorithm, substring

I have a string that consists of characters A,B,C and D and I am trying to calculate the length of the longest substring that has an equal amount of each one of these characters in any order. 
For example ABCDB would return 4, ABCC 0 and ADDBCCBA 8.

My code currently:

```
    public int longestSubstring(String word) {
        HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        for (int i = 0; i<word.length()-3; i++) {
            map.put(i, word.substring(i, i+4));
        }

        StringBuilder sb;   

        int longest = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i<map.size(); i++) {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(map.get(i));

            int a = 4;

            while (i<map.size()-a) {
                sb.append(map.get(i+a));
                a+= 4;
            }

            String substring = sb.toString();

            if (equalAmountOfCharacters(substring)) {
                int length = substring.length();
                if (length > longest)
                    longest = length;
            }

        }

    return longest;
}
```

This currently works pretty well if the string length is 10^4 but I'm trying to make it 10^5. Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are your strings always a multiple of 4, and can you only start your substrings 4-aligned?

Comment: String may be any length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Let's assume that `cnt(c, i)` is the number of occurrences of the character `c` in the prefix of length `i`.
2. A substring `(low, high]` has an equal amount of two characters `a` and `b` iff `cnt(a, high) - cnt(a, low) = cnt(b, high) - cnt(b, low)`, or, put it another way, `cnt(b, high) - cnt(a, high) = cnt(b, low) - cnt(a, low)`. Thus, each position is described by a value of `cnt(b, i) - cnt(a, i)`. Now we can generalize it for more that two characters: each position is described by a tuple `(cnt(a_2, i) - cnt(a_1, i), ..., cnt(a_k, i) - cnt(a_1, i))`, where `a_1 ... a_k` is the alphabet.
3. We can iterate over the given string and maintain the current tuple. At each step, we should update the answer by checking the value of `i - first_occurrence(current_tuple)`, where `first_occurrence` is a hash table that stores the first occurrence of each tuple seen so far. Do not forget to put a tuple of zeros to the hash map before iteration(it corresponds to an empty prefix).

Comment: @Deduplicator It is start-exclusive and end-inclusive. It is reversing common notation, but it is convenient to avoid `+/-1` when subtracting prefix sums.

Comment: Am I understanding it incorrect? Example: "aacc", Here, at pos 1 index tuple will look like : 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 . . . 0, 0, 0, -2 . (26 length)?

Answer (score 0):

If there were only A's and B's, then you could do something like this.

```
def longest_balanced(word):
    length = 0
    cumulative_difference = 0
    first_index = {0: -1}
    for index, letter in enumerate(word):
        if letter == 'A':
            cumulative_difference += 1
        elif letter == 'B':
            cumulative_difference -= 1
        else:
            raise ValueError(letter)
        if cumulative_difference in first_index:
            length = max(length, index - first_index[cumulative_difference])
        else:
            first_index[cumulative_difference] = index
    return length
```

Life is more complicated with all four letters, but the idea is much the same. Instead of keeping just one cumulative difference, for A's versus B's, we keep three, for A's versus B's, A's versus C's, and A's versus D's.

Comment: @Deduplicator It's Python.

Comment: Yes. But on a Java question, Python is no better than any other kind of pseudo-code, which is the point I wanted to make. (Not saying it's a bad idea at all, as the algorithm seems to be the OPs real question.)

Comment: @Deduplicator It's an algorithm question. If I wrote Java samples, I'd never have time to get any work done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all abstain from constructing any strings.
If you don't produce any (or nearly no) garbage, there's no need to collect it, which is a major plus.

Next, use a different data-structure:

I suggest 4 byte-arrays, storing the count of their respective symbol in the 4-span starting at the corresponding string-index.
That should speed it up considerably.

Comment: If efficiency is paramount, I think it's preferable to have 4 arrays of length `str.length()` rather than `str.length()` arrays of length 4.

Comment: @HollisWaite: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to cache cumulative counts of characters for each index of String -- that's where the real bottleneck is. Haven't thoroughly tested but something like the below should work.

```
public class Test {
    static final int LEN = 4;

    static class RandomCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private final Random mRandom = new Random();
        private final int mAlphabetLen;
        private final int mLen;
        private final int mOffset;

        RandomCharSequence(int pLen, int pOffset, int pAlphabetLen) {
            mAlphabetLen = pAlphabetLen;
            mLen = pLen;
            mOffset = pOffset;
        }

        public int length() {return mLen;}

        public char charAt(int pIdx) {
            mRandom.setSeed(mOffset + pIdx);
            return (char) (
                'A' +
                 (mRandom.nextInt() % mAlphabetLen + mAlphabetLen) % mAlphabetLen
            );
        }

        public CharSequence subSequence(int pStart, int pEnd) {
            return new RandomCharSequence(pEnd - pStart, pStart, mAlphabetLen);
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
            return (new StringBuilder(this)).toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] pArgs) {
        Stream.of("ABCDB", "ABCC", "ADDBCCBA", "DADDBCCBA").forEach(
            pWord -> System.out.println(longestSubstring(pWord))
        );

        for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
            final double len = Math.pow(10, i);
            if (len >= Integer.MAX_VALUE) break;

            System.out.println("Str len 10^" + i);
            for (int alphabetLen = 1; alphabetLen <= LEN; alphabetLen++) {
                final Instant start = Instant.now();
                final int val = longestSubstring(
                    new RandomCharSequence((int) len, 0, alphabetLen)
                );

                System.out.println(
                    String.format(
                        "  alphabet len %d; result %08d; time %s",
                        alphabetLen,
                        val,
                        formatMillis(ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(start, Instant.now()))
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }

    static String formatMillis(long millis) {
        return String.format(
            "%d:%02d:%02d.%03d",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) -
             TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) -
             TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(millis) -
             TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis))
        );
    }

    static int longestSubstring(CharSequence pWord) {
        // create array that stores cumulative char counts at each index of string
        // idx 0 = char (A-D); idx 1 = offset
        final int[][] cumulativeCnts = new int[LEN][];
        for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
            cumulativeCnts[i] = new int[pWord.length() + 1];
        }

        final int[] cumulativeCnt = new int[LEN];

        for (int i = 0; i < pWord.length(); i++) {
            cumulativeCnt[pWord.charAt(i) - 'A']++;
            for (int j = 0; j < LEN; j++) {
                cumulativeCnts[j][i + 1] = cumulativeCnt[j];
            }
        }

        final int maxResult = Arrays.stream(cumulativeCnt).min().orElse(0) * LEN;
        if (maxResult == 0) return 0;

        int result = 0;
        for (int initialOffset = 0; initialOffset < LEN; initialOffset++) {
            for (
                int start = initialOffset;
                start < pWord.length() - result;
                start += LEN
            ) {
                endLoop:
                for (
                    int end = start + result + LEN;
                    end <= pWord.length() && end - start <= maxResult;
                    end += LEN
                ) {
                    final int substrLen = end - start;
                    final int expectedCharCnt = substrLen / LEN;
                    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
                        if (
                            cumulativeCnts[i][end] - cumulativeCnts[i][start] !=
                             expectedCharCnt
                        ) {
                            continue endLoop;
                        }
                    }
                    if (substrLen > result) result = substrLen;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty nice way to do it. Works way better than mine but it still needs to be faster.

Comment: Code probably runs slow on certain input strings. I edited answer to avoid testing subsequences that have no chance of yielding improved result.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the occurrences of the characters in `word`. Then, a possible solution could be:

1. If `min` is the minimum number of occurrences of any character in `word`, then `min` is also the maximum possible number of occurrences of each character in the substring we are looking for. In the code below, `min` is `maxCount`.
2. We iterate over decreasing values of `maxCount`. At every step, the string we are searching for will have length `maxCount * alphabetSize`. We can view this as the size of a sliding window we can slide over `word`.
3. We slide the window over `word`, counting the occurrences of the characters in the window. If the window is the substring we are searching for, we return the result. Otherwise, we keep searching.

**[FIXED]** The code:

```
private static final int ALPHABET_SIZE = 4;

public int longestSubstring(String word) {
    // count
    int[] count = new int[ALPHABET_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char c = word.charAt(i);
        count[c - 'A']++;
    }
    int maxCount = word.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
        int cnt = count[i];
        if (cnt < maxCount) {
            maxCount = cnt;
        }
    }
    // iterate over maxCount until found
    boolean found = false;
    while (maxCount > 0 && !found) {
        int substringLength = maxCount * ALPHABET_SIZE;
        found = findSubstring(substringLength, word, maxCount);
        if (!found) {
            maxCount--;
        }
    }
    return found ? maxCount * ALPHABET_SIZE : 0;
}

private boolean findSubstring(int length, String word, int maxCount) {
    int startIndex = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    while (startIndex + length <= word.length()) {
        int[] count = new int[ALPHABET_SIZE];
        for (int i = startIndex; i < startIndex + length; i++) {
            char c = word.charAt(i);
            int cnt = ++count[c - 'A'];
            if (cnt > maxCount) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (equalValues(count, maxCount)) {
            found = true;
            break;
        } else {
            startIndex++;
        }
    }
    return found;
}

// Returns true if all values in c are equal to value
private boolean equalValues(int[] count, int value) {
    boolean result = true;
    for (int i : count) {
        if (i != value) {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**[MERGED]** This is Hollis Waite's solution using cumulative counts, but taking my observations at points 1. and 2. into consideration. This may improve performance for some inputs:

```
private static final int ALPHABET_SIZE = 4;

public int longestSubstring(String word) {
    // count
    int[][] cumulativeCount = new int[ALPHABET_SIZE][];
    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++) {
        cumulativeCount[i] = new int[word.length() + 1];
    }
    int[] count = new int[ALPHABET_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char c = word.charAt(i);
        count[c - 'A']++;
        for (int j = 0; j < ALPHABET_SIZE; j++) {
            cumulativeCount[j][i + 1] = count[j];
        }
    }
    int maxCount = word.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
        int cnt = count[i];
        if (cnt < maxCount) {
            maxCount = cnt;
        }
    }
    // iterate over maxCount until found
    boolean found = false;
    while (maxCount > 0 && !found) {
        int substringLength = maxCount * ALPHABET_SIZE;
        found = findSubstring(substringLength, word, maxCount, cumulativeCount);
        if (!found) {
            maxCount--;
        }
    }
    return found ? maxCount * ALPHABET_SIZE : 0;
}

private boolean findSubstring(int length, String word, int maxCount, int[][] cumulativeCount) {
    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = (startIndex + length) - 1;
    boolean found = true;
    while (endIndex < word.length()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++) {
            if (cumulativeCount[i][endIndex] - cumulativeCount[i][startIndex] != maxCount) {
                found = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            break;
        } else {
            startIndex++;
            endIndex++;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but your code doesn't always return the value it should. For example ABCDAAABCDABCD returns 4 when it should return 8 and it works way slower than my version.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed now and added some performance improvements.

Comment: First one is still very slow if the length of the string is 10^5. And the second one doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Can you post some input of size 10^4 and 10^5, with expected output? What error do you get from the second solution?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are K possible letters in a string of length N.  We could track the balance of letters seen with a vector **pos** of length K that is updated as follows:

- If letter 1 is seen, add (K-1, -1, -1, ...)
- If letter 2 is seen, add (-1, K-1, -1, ...)
- If letter 3 is seen, add (-1, -1, K-1, ...)

Maintain a hash that maps pos to the first string position where pos is reached. Balanced substrings occur whenever hash[pos] already exists and the substring value is s[hash[pos]:pos].

The cost of maintaining the hash is O(log N) so processing the string takes O(N log N).  How does this compare with solutions so far?  These types of problems tend to have linear solutions but I haven't come across one yet.

Here's some code demonstrating the idea for 3 letters and a run using biased random strings.  (Uniform random strings allow for solutions that are around half the string length, which is unwieldy to print).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random
from time import time

alphabet = "abc"
DIM = len(alphabet)


def random_string(n):
    # return a random string over choices[] of length n
    # distribution of letters is non-uniform to make matches harder to find
    choices = "aabbc"
    s = ''
    for i in range(n):
        r = random.randint(0, len(choices) - 1)
        s += choices[r]
    return s


def validate(s):
    # verify frequencies of each letter are the same
    f = [0, 0, 0]
    a2f = {alphabet[i] : i for i in range(DIM)}
    for c in s:
        f[a2f[c]] += 1
    assert f[0] == f[1] and f[1] == f[2]


def longest_balanced(s):
    """return length of longest substring of s containing equal
       populations of each letter in alphabet"""

    slen = len(s)
    p = [0 for i in range(DIM)]
    vec = {alphabet[0] : [2, -1, -1],
           alphabet[1] : [-1, 2, -1],
           alphabet[2] : [-1, -1, 2]}
    x = -1
    best = -1
    hist = {str([0, 0, 0]) : -1}

    for c in s:
        x += 1
        p = [p[i] + vec[c][i] for i in range(DIM)]
        pkey = str(p)

        if pkey not in hist:
            hist[pkey] = x
        else:
            span = x - hist[pkey]
            assert span % DIM == 0
            if span > best:
                best = span

                cand = s[hist[pkey] + 1: x + 1]
                print("best so far %d = [%d,%d]: %s" % (best,
                                                        hist[pkey] + 1,
                                                        x + 1,
                                                        cand))
                validate(cand)

    return best if best > -1 else 0


def main():
    #print longest_balanced( "aaabcabcbbcc" )

    t0 = time()
    s = random_string(1000000)
    print "generate time:", time() - t0
    t1 = time()
    best = longest_balanced( s )
    print "best:", best
    print "elapsed:", time() - t1


main()
```

Sample run on an input of 10^6 letters with an alphabet of 3 letters:

```
$ ./bal.py 
...
best so far 189 = [847894,848083]: aacacbcbabbbcabaabbbaabbbaaaacbcaaaccccbcbcbababaabbccccbbabbacabbbbbcaacacccbbaacbabcbccaabaccabbbbbababbacbaaaacabcbabcbccbabbccaccaabbcabaabccccaacccccbaacaaaccbbcbcabcbcacaabccbacccacca
best: 189
elapsed: 1.43609690666
```